# How to test if some numbers are uniformly distributed along an interval?

Tags: c++, algorithm, statistics, distribution

I am looking for an algorithm (preferably using a library in c++) or some idea to tell me if certain numbers statistically are distributed in an interval in a uniform manner or not. Imagine I have two strings: the first one is error free and the second has some errors at some points. I want to check if the position of errors in the string is statistically meaningful or not.

consider the following example. In the first case the errors are uniformly distributed and in the second on they are all at the end of the string which should my algorithm gives some alarms about it.

```
 error-free string: 0110110101010110101 (3 errors occur at pos:5,12,15 )
 erroneous string : 0110010101000100101
```

sedond example :

```
 error-free string: 0110110101010110101 (3 errors occur at pos:17,18,19 )
 erroneous string : 0110110101010110010
```

I can say the errors in the first data is normal but not in the second one.

So far I ended up to this idea: I want to split the string to equal bins, suppose the string length is 100. I choose to have 10 bin size 10. Then I look at the total number of errors in the string which we can suppose to be 10. I expect to see 1 error in each bin. Now I calculate how far is statistically my observation from my expectation. Anyone has any idea if this method is correct or not?  And if it works, how big should be each bin. Should it depends to the number of errors as well?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/is-there-a-simple-test-for-uniform-distributions

Comment: Look up the chi-squared test.   Bear in mind that, by their nature, statistical tests can have false positives and false negatives.

Comment: How about a histogram + least-squares fit of a constant on that historgram? Chi-square will tell you how good your distribution is because it models a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you're suggesting, in which you split the string into bins expecting to see the number of errors more or less evenly distributed among the bins, is blind to patterns such as "every tenth position has an error". I believe you need a more general way to distinguish the case in which the occurrences of errors are indifferent to the positions from the case in which there is some pattern to the positions where errors occur.

In other words, I think you're actually looking for a way to measure the extent to which a binary string is random, or more precisely, patternless. The ultimate mathematical definition of string patternlessness is the string's [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), defined as the length of the shortest program that outputs the string. Sadly, the Kolmogorov complexity is not computable.

One feasible way to compute the patternlessness of a binary string is to use the [Linear Hadamard Spectral Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform). The test can be implemented using the [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) to run in time `O(n logn)` where `n` is the length of the string. However, it seems to me like there is no ready to use implementation of the test in C++.

Assuming you're willing to compromise a little bit on the robustness of the test for the sake of ease of implementation, you can use the following  approach: to measure the patternlessness of the string, simply [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/) a file whose content is the string, and then check the compression ratio. The worse the compression, the more patternless the string is. The approach relies on the fact that gzip encompasses some aspects of Kolmogorov complexity. In particular, the existence of somewhat easy to detect patterns improves the compression ratio.

Comment: Perhaps the Kolmogorov complexity isn't computable, but a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov–Smirnov_test) is.

Comment: If you want to do the Hadamard spectral test, use a Fast Walsh Transform rather than an FFT.  [Implementations are available in C++](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/walsh/walsh.html).

Comment: @pjs, thanks for the relevant comments. I wasn't at all aware of the existence of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.